# Best way to add DOM Element to Body with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, innerhtml, appendchild

I need to put at every page this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:fixed; text-align:center; left:30px; widht: 200px;bottom: -12px;"> <div class="card" style="position: relative;background: #EC2D2D;border-radius: 5px;padding: 20px 0 0px 0;box-sizing: border-box;box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;"> <h1 class="title" style="position: relative;z-index: 1;border-left: 5px solid #FFFFFF;margin: 0 0 25px;padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 32px;font-weight: 600;/* text-transform: uppercase; */">50% less</h1> <div class="button-container" style="margin: 0 20px;text-align: center;"> <button style="outline: 0;cursor: pointer;position: relative;display: inline-block;background: 0;color: #EC2D2D;background: #fff;width: 170px;border: 2px solid #C70A0A; padding: 10px 0;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 1;text-transform: uppercase;overflow: hidden;-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;"><span>Bid and Book Now</span></button> </div> <div class="footer" style="margin: 20px 0 0;color: #FFFFFF !important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 100;text-align: center;"> <p style="color: inherit;text-decoration: none;-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;">BEST RATES - only on website</p> <p style="font-size: 10px;">End in: 1d 2h 33m</p></div> </div> <div class="card alt" style="position: absolute;top: 40px;border: 3px solid #ED2553;right: -40px;z-index: 10;width: 80px;height: 80px;background: #FFFFFF;background-image: url(&quot;http://i.imgur.com/32T7CPH.jpg&quot;);border-radius: 100%;box-shadow: none;padding: 0;-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;"> </div> </div> ';
```

This code doesn't work well at every page.  Also, I think its very slow and makes problem for some pages.  How can I write this with `appendChild` or something similar?

I can't use JQuery's `append` because I have to use plain JavaScript code.

What would this code look like with `appendChild`?

Comment: Which problem do you have at "some page" ?

Comment: My console log block - and rewrite all body dom elements...

Comment: Yes because you are setting a new content for the whole HTML. Your code said: take the innerHTML of body (that is a string) add to it a string (your string between apex) and set this new string to the innerHTML, you are not appending it.

Comment: So how I can solve this and use appendChild ?

Comment: What is the javascript code of .append - jquery function? How that function work?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Yes, I want to know how I can write this with appendChild?

Comment: This code I need to put at external page as widget so its must work good...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method **`appendChild` take a node** and add this node to the element on which it was called.

```
var node = document.createElement("DIV");  
var textNode = document.createTextNode("My Div content");
node.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

You can't use `appendChild` with a string containing the whole html.

What you can do is create a node. Set its `innerHTML` with the huge string. Then append the node to the body.

---

Code should be something similar to this:

```
var content = ....
var newNode = document.createElement("DIV");  
newNode.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: this also dont work: var node = document.createElement('DIV');  
var textNode = document.createTextNode('<div class="card" style="position: relative;background: #EC2D2D;border-radius: 5px;padding: 20px 0 0px 0;box-sizing: border-box;box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;"> <h1 class="title" style="position: relative;z-indm/32T7CPH.jpg&quot;);border-radius: 100%;box-shadow: none;padding: 0;-webkit-transition: .3s ease;transition: .3s ease;"> </div>');
node.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(node);

Comment: Is not what I said. 1 Create a node. 2 set innerHTML of that node. 3. append the node to the body

Answer (score 2):

in vanilla js you can use `.appendChild` which will add to the element caller the node passed as argument.

In your case (with a string as dom element/s to be insert) you could do this trick:

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = "<your dom code>";

while (el.firstChild) document.body.appendChild(el.firstChild);
```

It's a bit rude but this way you'll create an element, filling it with your string dom and then move each child to the document.body

---

Here a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd0xbuyf/) as example using your code

Comment: hm,no, I get: #text
baseURI: "http://dssdfl.com/"
childNodes: NodeList[0]
data: " "
firstChild: null
lastChild: null
length: 1
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "#text"
nodeType: 3
nodeValue: " "
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: body
parentNode: body
previousElementSibling: div
previousSibling: div
textContent: " "
wholeText: " "
__proto__: Text

Comment: I tested the script using the string code you posted in the question (in this page) and worked,  check againg please. here a jsfiddle as example https://jsfiddle.net/xd0xbuyf/

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness I used a `while` in case you'll have more than 1 node like `"<div></div> text <div></div>"` but do not worry it's fast (talking about performance)