# Why failed to generate dynamic table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate dynamic table with Javascript, want to generate table like this table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td> 3  </td>
  </tr>
 ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

then I write a script to generate the table, but I can't get correct table, I don't know where has problem, could anyone help to check it?

```
var arrName = ['aaa', 'bbb','ccc'];
var arrNumber = [3, 2, 4];
if (arrName.length != 0 && arrNumber.length != 0)
{            
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    var tr_header = document.createElement('tr');

    var th_owner = document.createElement('th');
    var th_number = document.createElement('th');

    th_owner.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Owner'));
    th_number.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Number'));

    tr_header.appendChild(th_owner);
    tr_header.appendChild(th_number);

    tbody.appendChild(tr_header);

    for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++)
    {
        var tr_details = document.createElement('tr');

        var td_owner = document.createElement('td');
        var td_count = document.createElement('td');

        td_owner.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrName[i].toString()));
        td_count.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrNumber[i].toString()));
        tr_details.appendChild(td_owner);
        tr_details.appendChild(td_count);

        tbody.appendChild(tr_details);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbody);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? If I run your code it seems to create the table correctly on my end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to add DOM Element to Body with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655318/best-way-to-add-dom-element-to-body-with-javascript)

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/y2jboszh/8/ you forgot to append the table at the document.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly. Maybe you just missed to add the table to the page.
I just added bellow code to the end:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body[0].appendChild(table);
```

Check the test page I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            var arrName = ['aaa', 'bbb','ccc'];
            var arrNumber = [3, 2, 4];
            if (arrName.length != 0 && arrNumber.length != 0)
            {

                var table = document.createElement('table');
                var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

                var tr_header = document.createElement('tr');

                var th_owner = document.createElement('th');
                var th_number = document.createElement('th');

                th_owner.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Owner'));
                th_number.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Number'));

                tr_header.appendChild(th_owner);
                tr_header.appendChild(th_number);

                tbody.appendChild(tr_header);

                for (var i = 0; i < arrName.length; i++)
                {
                    var tr_details = document.createElement('tr');

                    var td_owner = document.createElement('td');
                    var td_count = document.createElement('td');

                    td_owner.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrName[i].toString()));
                    td_count.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrNumber[i].toString()));

                    tr_details.appendChild(td_owner);
                    tr_details.appendChild(td_count);

                    tbody.appendChild(tr_details);
                }

                table.appendChild(tbody);

                var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
                body[0].appendChild(table);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can get the table after adding code with as your note, thanks: var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body[0].appendChild(table);